# Multithreaded download manager and DataGridView

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, task

I'm trying to download two files at the same time and somehow I'm getting an "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
            var downloadthread1 = new FileDownload();
            var downloadthread2 = new FileDownload();

            downloadthread1.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChanged;
            downloadthread1.DownloadCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
            downloadthread2.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChanged;
            downloadthread2.DownloadCompleted += DownloadCompleted;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => downloadthread1.Start(downloadDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), 0));
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => downloadthread2.Start(downloadDataGridView.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), 1));
            Task.WaitAll();
```

This part works, but when I do this in a loop for it not seems to work:

```
            FileDownload[] fileDownloads = new FileDownload[2];
            fileDownloads[0] = new FileDownload();
            fileDownloads[1] = new FileDownload();

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                fileDownloads[i].DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChanged;
                fileDownloads[i].DownloadCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
                fileDownloads[i].m_UrlQueue.Enqueue(m_Downloader.m_UrlQueue.Dequeue());
                string downloadPath = downloadDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fileDownloads[i].Start(downloadPath, i));
            }
```

As the ReSharper suggested it may be a problem of something called "Access to modified closure", besides the fact that I don't change the i index it seems to be the problem.

I have to use the index in the thread in order to update the DataGridView in the DownloadProgressChanged and Completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resharpes suggests you not to use variable **i** inside your for loop. You have to make new variable and assign **i** to it, then use your new variable inside the loop.

Some basic code to demonstrate the concept:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            new Thread(() => Console.Write(i)).Start();
        }
```

This won't probably print 0123456789 because when you run multiple threads at once and they use global variable, there is a possibility that thread5 will access **i** later than thread6.

To solve this, we have to do this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int temp = i;
            new Thread(() => Console.Write(temp)).Start();
        }
```

Because **temp** is not a global variable, but local for each thread, so there will be no problem and output will be 0123456789 all the times.

Comment: This seems to solve the problem, Wonderful how a minor modification made all the difference, Thank you!